# trace connections in network?

Tags: r, igraph

How can I find/isolate all the upstream/downstream connections to a node in a directed graph?

For instance, in R igraph I create two paths `A->B->C` and `D->B->E`:

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_literal(A-+B-+C, D-+B-+E)

plot(g, vertex.color = "grey", edge.color = "blue")
```

[image]

By selecting the node `C` or `A`, I would like to retrieve `A->B->C` and `D->B->C`. What is this operation called? Is it possible to invoke this functionality through R/igraph?

Comment: Should selecting `C` also retrieve `D->B->C` in addition to `A->B->C`? The graph has no way to distinguish this, does it?

Comment: I agree with @mathematical.coffee - while the input side might know that they are separate paths, and the graph is plotted to suggest they are at right angles to one another, this is arbitrary. Are you able to create an attribute or label at the time of input to remember this data?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: you're right, I've corrected my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This completes the answer started by @Psidom.

You seem to be looking only for *maximal* paths to or from a node. A maximal path out of a node ends in a sink. A maximal path into a node begins at a source. I provide slightly different solutions for the paths into or out of a node.

Using your sample data:

```
sources = which(degree(g, v = V(g), mode = "in")==0,  useNames = T)
sinks   = which(degree(g, v = V(g), mode = "out")==0, useNames = T)

## Paths out of A
all_simple_paths(g, from = "A", to = sinks)
[[1]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B C

[[2]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B E

## Paths into C
lapply(sources, function(x) all_simple_paths(g, from =x, to = "C"))
$A
$A[[1]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B C

$D
$D[[1]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] D B C
```

Answer (score 1):

In R `igraph` package, there are two functions suitable for searching connections based on two algorithms -- `graph.dfs`(depth first search) and `graph.bfs`(breadth first search).

```
library(igraph)
graph.dfs(g, "A", neimode = "out", dist = T)$dist
A B C D E 
0 1 2 0 2

graph.bfs(g, "A", neimode = "out", dist = T)$dist
A B C D E 
0 1 2 0 2
```

Another useful function for your case is `all_shortest_path()`, which gives all path starting from a vertex:

```
all_shortest_paths(g, "A", mode = "out")
$res
$res[[1]]
+ 1/5 vertex, named:
[1] A

$res[[2]]
+ 2/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B

$res[[3]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B C

$res[[4]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B E


$nrgeo
[1] 1 1 1 0 1
```

Even though this does not exactly solve your problem, it might provide some useful hint.